# i'm new in es6 javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const name = document.getElementById('fname');
const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
const out = document.getElementById('out');
const gname = name.value;

// greet function
const greet = (n) => {
    return `hello ${n}`;
};
// output
const pout = (fname) => {
    out.innerHTML = greet(fname);
};

// call event
submit.addEventListener("click", () => { pout(gname) });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Please enter your name"><br>
<button id="submit" >Submit</button>
<br><br>
OUTPUT: <span id="out"></span>
```

**Please help me to find the error in the code, i'm learning es6 JavaScript, can't find the error**

Comment: what is the `error`?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you want to display the value of the input on `output`. In that case, you should be passing `name.value` to the `greet()` function!

I have removed the `gname` constant, as they are not needed here. However, you may instead move gname within the `output` function since it is only needed within the function, and not anywhere else.

```js
const name = document.getElementById('fname');
const out = document.getElementById('out');
const submit = document.getElementById('submit');

// greet function
const greet = (n) => {
    return `hello ${n}`;
};
// output
const pout = () => {
    out.innerHTML = greet(name.value);
};

// call event
submit.addEventListener("click", (event) => { 
  pout();   
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" ><br>
<button id="submit" >Submit</button>
<br><br>
OUTPUT: <span id="out"></span>
```

Comment: Your removed const submit ,then how submit event listner works??

Comment: @NavneetGupta Opps sorry I removed the wrong variable. Now it should work. You can check it now.

Answer (score 1):

The `gname` is assigned the input element value - `const gname = name.value;` and your `input` element is empty initially. So everytime you call `pout(gname)`, gname will have empty string. If you want to pass the entered value in input, pass `name.value` and not `gname`.

```
submit.addEventListener("click", () => { pout(name.value) });
```

```js
const name = document.getElementById('fname');
const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
const out = document.getElementById('out');

// greet function
const greet = (n) => {
  return `hello ${n}`;
};
// output
const pout = (fname) => {
  out.innerHTML = greet(fname);
};

// call event
submit.addEventListener("click", () => {
  pout(name.value)
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Please enter your name"><br>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<br><br> OUTPUT: <span id="out"></span>
```